# Has the Meta-crisis Doctor grown his own TARDIS?

Tags: doctor-who

At the end of Journey's End, the final episode of Season 4, on the beach when the rift closes the Doctor gives "tentwo" (the Meta-crisis Doctor) a piece of TARDIS coral and tells him to grow his own.

Have we heard that he actually has and is traveling with Rose on adventures?

Answer (score 10):

### We've never seen him again and he never got a piece of the TARDIS anyway.

As much as Doctor Who has canon, only what we see on screen in an episode counts. The scene in which the Meta-Crisis Doctor received a piece of the TARDIS is a deleted scene, so it never happened (and give the progress of events that *did* make it to the screen, probably couldn't have happened during a cut-away).

Even if he did have a piece of the TARDIS, RTD wrote that it would have taken thousands of years to grow. RTD had a line for the Doctor-Donna to think of a way to speed up the process "by the power of 59," whatever that means, but again--deleted part of a deleted scene.

And even given all of that, the Meta-Crisis Doctor has never been seen again on screen or in any other Doctor Who story.

Comment: But either ways, we have never actually heard of having his own TARDIS or travelling with Rose. Although if the deleted scene can be considered canon, then meta-ten has a piece which he could use.

Comment: Because someone tried to edit my answer to add that Russell T. says the TARDIS fragment is canon: Russell T. has explicitly said that he has neither authority to establish canon  (DWM #388) nor interest in doing so (DWM #356). An answer based on the content of the DVD boxed set material should be made independently, not made an addendum to my answer because edits should not substantially change the point of the post they're made to.

Answer (score 2):

> In the original script, the Doctor was meant to give TARDIS coral to
>   the part-human Doctor on the assumption that a whole new TARDIS could
>   be grown from it, but it was cut.

http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Meta-Crisis_Tenth_Doctor

Comment: What's this quoting?

Comment: It is directly form the Tardis Wikipedia site.. so its in quotation marks

Comment: When quoting from Wikias, you must also include a link to what you're quoting.  This is per their [copyright terms](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will do so from next time.

Answer (score 0):

No The Doctor clone does not have the sufficient items to grown his own TARDIS...

The reason is the following...

As stated in the Wiki for TARDIS

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TARDIS

> TARDISes are bioships that are grown from a species of coral
>   presumably indigenous to Gallifrey, as stated in "The Impossible
>   Planet" (2006), and it can take years to complete one.

The main thing to take from this quote is that the species of coral that TARDISes are grown from are most likely only indigenous to Gallifrey as stated.

The problem is that the scene where The Doctor gives the coral to the clone is a deleted scene... Now then deleted scenes are not considered canon, so we can ignore that fact.  After taking consideration that we have not seen any actual coral in a live broadcast of Doctor Who, perhaps it may have been shown Pre-Time War but it's not shown in New Who, we can conclude that there are no more in existence  because Gallifrey is gone...  Perhaps it's really rare, and it's not stated if the coral is grown inside The TARDIS either...  So the clone of The Doctor would not have ever gotten his hands on one.